# Grease Pencil Frame-By-Frame + bones?

Tags: armature, grease-pencil

newbie here. I'm trying to figure out a workflow for cut-out animation that allows you to swap drawings via grease pencil. So the question is:

Is it possible to combine grease pencil's frame by frame with blender's armature? Or are there better ways?

Thank you!

Comment: I… am honestly not sure. I remember trying once and it failed, but it looked possible more recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Armature animation and GP animation can be used together, Armature keyframes will be in the regular Dopesheet or Action editor, while GP keyframes will be in the Grease pencil Dope sheet editor. Use bendy bones to get smoother results.

An useful tool is the Time Offset modifier, setted to Fixed frame instead of default Regular: it allows to jump frome one GP frame to another (i.e. 10 different eyes shapes) simply keyframing its offset value, or using a bone to control it with a driver.

[image]

Comment: I tried to do it, but can't get it do work. Do you know any tutorials I could follow?

Comment: @josh_sanfelici how do you make the grease pencil frame connect to the bones?